# Update components after removing one from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore

Please tell me how to properly update the PathItems component after deleting one of the Items. The component itself disappears from the list but its description remains (see in the attached screenshot).

PathItems component:

```
import Item from "./PathItem";
import FullDecript from "./PathFullDescription";

import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import {Col, Row} from "react-bootstrap";

const PathItems = (props) => {
    const divStyle = {
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        height: '85vh'
    };

    const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col className="pl-0 border-right border-dark" style={divStyle}>
                    {props.pathDescription && props.pathDescription.map(item => (
                        <Item
                            key={item.id}
                            item={item}
                            onInfoChange={setInfo}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    {info !== null ? <FullDecript {...info}/> : null}
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        pathDescription: state.firestore.ordered.pathDescription
    }
}

export default compose(
    firestoreConnect(()=> ['pathDescription']),
    connect(mapStateToProps)
)(PathItems);
```

Item component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Col, Row, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

const PathItem = ({ item, onInfoChange }) => {
    const [info, setInfo] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        onInfoChange(info); // pass info back to parent
    }, [info, onInfoChange]);

    const _onClick = event => {
        setInfo(item);
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Card as="a"
                  style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                  className={'mb-2'}
                  onClick={ _onClick }>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Row className="align-items-center">
                        <Col xs={1}>
                            <img
                                alt="Logo"
                                src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/font-awesome/1792/arrows-alt-256.png"
                                width="25"
                                height="25"
                                className="d-inline-block align-top"/>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={7}>
                            <h5>{item.title}</h5>
                            {item.sDescript}
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={4} className="text-right">
                            <label>{item.length}600 km</label>
                            <img
                                alt="Logo"
                                src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/developer-set-3/128/right-512.png"
                                width="25"
                                height="25"
                                className="d-inline-block pull-right"
                            />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default PathItem;
```

FullDecript component:

```
import React from "react";
import MapForm from "../Map/MapForm";

import { Col, Row, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { deleteItem } from "../../store/actions/progectActions";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const FullDecript = ({ id, title, fDescript }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleRemove = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(deleteItem(id));
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <h2>{title}</h2>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col className="pb-2">
                    {fDescript}
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Button variant="link">Add to favorite</Button>
                <Button variant="link" onClick={ handleRemove }>Delete</Button>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <div>
                    <MapForm />
                </div>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}

export default FullDecript;
```

And delete function:

```
export const deleteItem = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore }) => {
        // make async call to database
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        firestore.collection('pathDescription').doc(id).delete().then(
            () => {
                dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS' });
            }).catch(err => {
            dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_ITEM_ERROR' });
        })
    }
}
```

Reducer component

```
const initialState = [{}];

export default function userInfo (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
            console.log('Add item text', action.textInfo);
            return state;
        case 'ADD_ITEM_ERROR':
            console.log('Add item text error', action.err);
            return state;
        case 'DELETE_ITEM_SUCCESS':
            console.log('Delete item succes');
            return state;
        case 'DELETE_ITEM_ERROR':
            console.log('Delete item error')
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

[The contents of the component FullDecript remain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svuxW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component looks like this:

```
            <Row>
                <Col className="pl-0 border-right border-dark" style={divStyle}>
                    {props.pathDescription && props.pathDescription.map(item => (
                        <Item
                            key={item.id}
                            item={item}
                            onInfoChange={setInfo}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    {info !== null ? <FullDecript {...info}/> : null}
                </Col>
            </Row>
```

And your problem is that after deleting the item , `props.pathDescription` will be of size 0 (so the `.map` will not render any item), but `FullDecript` remains. That's because you don't clear the `info`. You just delete the item from the `pathDescription`.

you can do this in Item component:

```
    useEffect(() => () => {
        onInfoChange(null); // pass null info back to parent, on unmount
    }, []);
```

to update the parent info when an item is removed.

Ps: It still needs more work, since you have n items, but an only one description element. so there should be a `select` logic to let us to display the details of only the selected item.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it partially works.
Once there are no items in the list.
When an item is removed and the list has other content the component **FullDecript** remains.

Comment: @BohdanKolisbik try way 1 that i suggested. this way `FullDecript` will get removed when you remove an item/

Comment: @BohdanKolisbik and if it didn't work it's because every component is trying to set the info of `FullDecript`, which is wrong. you should add a state variable to determine who is the selected item and is shown on `FullDecript`. currently all of your items are owner of `FullDecript` , so it's hard to manage it. after creating a state, you can bind it to the last item in the list for example, and bind the existing condition of the `FullDecript` to the existing of that selected item.